# how to improve my performance for this complex query | Laravel , Datatabels

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, laravel-5, datatables

Hi everyone i have a very complex query to get Finance data,
its like 4 Join and when the data is more than 1000 it getting slow when it loads in datatables
how i can make it faster

this is the controller code for ajax :

```
  $financial_entries = FinanceEntryMod::select([
        DB::raw("ROUND(( 
            select SUM(finance_transaction.equivalent) from finance_transaction  where 
            finance_transaction.entry_id = financial_entries.id and
            finance_transaction.type = 'credit' 
        ), 2) as eqivalent_sum"),
        'financial_entries.id',
        'financial_entries.created_by',
        'financial_entries.branch_id',
        'financial_entries.order_id',
        'financial_entries.number',
        DB::raw('IFNULL(branches.name, IFNULL(v2_branches.name, "main_branch")) AS branch_name'),
        'financial_entries.v2_order_id as v2_order_id',
        'financial_entries.v2_document_id as v2_document_id',
        'financial_entries.date',
        'financial_entries.is_generated',
        'financial_entries.note',
        'financial_entries.created_at',
        'financial_entries.updated_at',
        DB::raw('
            DATE_FORMAT(financial_entries.date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS new_date,
            DATE_FORMAT(financial_entries.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") AS new_created_at
        ')
    ])
    ->leftJoin('branches', function ($join) {
        $join->on("branches.id", "=", "financial_entries.branch_id");
    })
    ->leftJoin('finance_transaction', function ($join) {
        $join->on("financial_entries.id", "=", "finance_transaction.entry_id");
    })
    ->leftJoin('finance_accounts', function ($join) {
        $join->on("finance_accounts.id", "=", "finance_transaction.account_id");
    })
    ->leftJoin('v2_branches', function ($join) { 
        $join->on("v2_branches.id", "=", "finance_accounts.v2_branch_id"); 
    })
    ->where('financial_entries.is_deleted', '=', '0')
    ->groupBy('financial_entries.id');
```

and in the script :
im using this

```
   "pageLength": 30,
        "serverSide"   : true,
        "processing"   : true,
        "columns":
```

please help me to improve it thanks all

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL, the `SHOW CREATE TABLE,` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: ok i found the problem ...
its in this sum`DB::raw("ROUND(( 
            select SUM(finance_transaction.equivalent) from finance_transaction  where 
            finance_transaction.entry_id = financial_entries.id and
            finance_transaction.type = 'credit' 
        ), 2) as eqivalent_sum"),` 
but i need this sum to get the result

Comment: when i delete this row , i got the data with in less then 5.s 
if i add it again the query get slower and i got the data with more than 22.s

Comment: To provide specific help, please provide the 3 things I asked for.